# Алгоритм определения времени начала события

Tags: python, алгоритм, события, время, pandas

Имеется таблица с информацией о неких событиях. О каждом из событий известно следующее (колонки таблицы):
 - порядковый номер в хронологическом порядке
 - время окончания
 - количество этапов
 - максимальная продолжительность каждого этапа
Продолжительность каждого этапа внутри события - случайная величина, которая может меняться в диапазоне от нуля до значения, указанного в четвертой колонке.
Как, основываясь на этих данных, максимально правдоподобно определить время начала каждого события?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте сперва переформулируем задачу коротко: "Каково среднее время события, состоящего из `K` этапов, если продолжительность каждого этапа - независимая случайная величина от 0 до `T`?"

Поскольку этапы независимы (например, если первый оказался очень продолжительным, то это не значит, что второй будет коротким и т.д. (другая аналогия: если в казино 10 раз подряд выпало красное, то это не значит, что вероятность выпадение чёрного увеличилась - как было 0.5, так и осталось)), а случайная величина равномерно распределена от 0 до T, легко определиться со средним временем одного этапа - это `T/2`.

Соответственно, на K этапах среднее время должно быть `K*T/2`. Здесь можно было бы оценить ожидаемый интервал времени `[t0, t1]` и вероятность, что реальная продолжительная события t попадёт в него, но, судя по всему, в этой задаче это не требуется.

Возвращаемся к исходной задаче: для каждого события известно время окончания, а среднюю продолжительность мы установили. Чтобы найти время начала события требуется из времени окончания вычесть продолжительность.

**Дополнение:**

Автор уточнил, что номера событий идут в хронологическом порядке. Это значит, что первоначальную оценку `K*T/2` (которую предлагаю считать разумной, учитывая отсутствие информации о распределении случайной величины) можно ещё улучшить.

Формулируем вторую половину задачи: есть таблица из `N` строк вида

```
0, T0, F0,
1, T1, F1,
2, T2, F2,
...
```

В этой таблице события отсортированы в хронологическом порядке (чем раньше событие началось, тем оно выше в таблице). Соответственно, имеем в первом столбце номер события, во втором - приблизительную его продолжительность (**это как раз требуется установить**), в последнем - точное время окончания.

Имея такую таблицу, мы можем строить вектор `U0, U1, ...` (уточнённых времён), а затем проверять, насколько они хороши (правдоподобны). Жёсткое условие такое: этот вектор должен соответствовать зафикисрованному хронологическому порядку (т.е. времена `Fi-Ui` должны соответствовать номерам Ni первого столбца). А мягкое условие - разница примерного и уточнённого времён `Ti-Ui` должна быть *не слишком большой*.

Теперь нам надо сформулировать критерий максимального правдоподобия уточнённых значений из второго столбца. Мы хотим минимизировать сумму квадратичных отклонений `Ti-Ui`^2? Или есть другая метрика, к которой надо стремиться? Ещё было бы полезно посмотреть на примеры входных данных и ожидаемые "правильные" ответы к ним (чтобы лучше понять, что требуется).

Comment: Из того, что это независимая случайная величина не следует, что центр распределения находится ровно посередине. Данных о характеристиках каждого этапа у меня нет. Есть только одна таблица.

Comment: Если нет информации о распределении, то о чём вообще вопрос? Зачем писать в тэгах pandas и python, когда нет достаточных данных для решения?

Comment: У меня тут гипотеза возникла: в формулировке задачи "Порядковый номер" - это id строки? Или что-то более интеллектуальное (например, этот номер мог бы указывать, в каком порядке события начинаются).

Comment: Да, порядковые номера идут в хронологическом порядке, почти без пропусков

Comment: Это важное дополнение, я расширил ответ.